# Optimizing Cuda kernel regarding normalisation of array

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu, pycuda

I'm trying to normalise the array as follows.

1. Pick the first two elements of the array, find the sum and divide them using that sum.
2. Do the same for rest of the elements.

It works fine. But when I increase the dimension of the array, time complexity comes into picture. I've given my code below.

```
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np

mod=SourceModule("""
__global__ void addition(float* a,float* c,float* d)
{
int i=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
for (i=0;i<=4;++i)
{
    int sum=0.0;
    for (int j=0;j<=1;++j)
    {
        sum+=a[2*i+j];
    }
c[i]=sum;
}
for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<=1;++j)
    {
        d[2*i+j]=a[2*i+j]/c[i];
    }
}
}
""")

addition=mod.get_function("addition")
a=np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,2,1]).astype(np.float32)
c=np.zeros_like(a)
d=np.zeros_like(a)
addition(drv.In(a),drv.InOut(c),drv.InOut(d),block=(1,8,1))
print d
```

The result of d is [0.33333334 0.66666669 0.75 0.25 0.40000001 0.60000002 0.666666669 0.33333334]. Can anyone suggest some ideas to optimize the code?

Comment: Why do you bother calculating `int i=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;` if you're immediately going to discard it ?

Comment: @PaulR: I'm new to PyCuda. Is it something wrong in initiating 'i' like that ?

Comment: And why are you asking about optimising what is effectively a completely serial code which computes a handful of FLOPs? Also, why are you performing the initial summation in integer? Is that deliberate?

Comment: You need to read up on the CUDA architecture - there is absolutely no point writing code that will only run as a single serial thread on one core of your GPU card.

Comment: @talonmies: Its not delibrate. Is there any way to parallelise the code?

Comment: Of course this can be parallelised, but the real question is *why would you want to?*. If you have a real world example which involves more than this trivial operation on 8 floating point numbers, please explain what it is. An optimal kernel design will depend on the size of the input data and the nature of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

If your real application was just summing a pair of values from `a`, storing that sum in `c` and then normalising the pair of values with the sum and storing them in `d`, something like this would be reasonable:

```
__global__ void addition(float* a, float* c, float* d)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

    float2* avec = reinterpret_cast<float2*>(a);
    float2* dvec = reinterpret_cast<float2*>(d);

    float2 val = avec[idx];
    float sum = val.x + val.y;
    val.x \= sum;
    val.y \= sum;

    c[idx] = sum;
    dvec[idx] = val;     
}
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled, never tested, not guaranteed not to set your GPU on fire, use at own risk]

Here a vector type is used to improve memory throughput, with each thread processing a single pair of values. For N values, run N/2 threads. If you have more than 131070 input values (so 65535 pairs), you will need to modify the kernel to process more than one input. I will leave that as an exercise for the reader, should such an eventuality arise.